# Logback file per logger dynamicaly

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have "special" requirement on loggin - I need every logger in separate file.

Java

```
Logger log1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("dynamic.log1");
Logger log2 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("dynamic.log2");
//...
```

Then I want logback any output from `log1` to be written to file `log1.log` and so on. Is it possible to "dynamicaly" create new `appender`'s like that with logback?

Can some other logging framework be used to solve this use-case?

I could configure appenders manualy but this is what I want to avoid. Like whenever I add `dynamic` logger, new appender/file is accordingly created.

**EDIT**:

I implemented custom discriminator:

```java
public class LoggerBasedDiscriminator extends AbstractDiscriminator<ILoggingEvent> {
    private static final String LOGGER_NAME = "loggerName";
    @Override
    public String getDiscriminatingValue(ILoggingEvent e) {
        return e.getLoggerName();
    }
    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return LOGGER_NAME;
    }
}
```

And then my appender config looks like this:

```xml
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="cz.svobol.logging.LoggerBasedDiscriminator">
        <key>loggerName</key>
        <defaultValue>root</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${loggerName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>${loggerName}.log</file>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SiftingAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender).

This way you have one appender that can divide the log into different files dynamically.